# Python list count command

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a list ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] and I would like to know if any of those 4 elements are found or not.

I tried to use count command in list but this function can check a specific element. Is there any other function which checks the all elements in the list?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could loop through second list and check if they exist.

Here you will create a list of elements which you want to check against the list of elements you are looking in. You remove the elements as they are found, if all the elements in the list exist in second list, they all are removed. If not items remain there. Final size of the list determines if the list contains all your elements or not.

```
firstList = ['a','b','c','d']

secondList = ['c','d','e']

for element in firstList:
    if element in secondList:
        firstList.remove(element)

if len(firstList) == 0:
    print("all elements in secondList")

else:
    print("some elements are not in secondList")
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.Series.isin` should work. It will return a boolean value if a value in your provided list is in the comparison list.

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = pd.Series(list(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']))
compareList = mylist.isin(list('AC'))

print(compareList)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be fairly simply by using set intersection operation, `&`.

```
found = ['A', 'C', 'E', 'F']
to_check = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

s_found = set(found)
s_to_check = set(to_check)

found_in_to_check = s_found & s_to_check

print(sorted(found_in_to_check))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'C']
```